# PHP: Format variable by predetermined CSV order... but Why this code as function breaks?

Tags: php, function, csv, explode, implode

This code works perfectly... but why I got error using it as PHP function?

```
$name = '1 value';
$age  = '2 value';
$date = '3 value';

$string = "date, name, age"; //default CSV file Column order
```

Will get great results:

> ```
> date, name, age
>
> date|name|age
> 3 value|1 value|2 value|
> ```

By using this code:

```
echo $string.'<br/>'; 

echo implode("|", explode(", ", $string)).'<br/><br/>';

    $line='';
    foreach(explode(", ", $string) as $str)    {
            $line .= $$str.'|';
    }
    echo $line;
```

I code this function:

```
<?php
function toImplode($string)
{
    $line = '';
    foreach (explode(", ", $string) as $str) {
        $line .= $$str . '|';
    }
    return $line;
}

echo 'Variable to line formatted order is:<br/> ' . toImplode($string) . '<br/>';
```

But I got this error:

```
> Notice: Undefined variable: name in on line 22 
> Notice: Undefined variable: age in on line 22 
> Notice: Undefined variable: date in on line 22
```

I can't understand why.

Comment: I'm confused when you say "function works perfectly" and " I got error using this code as PHP function" in the same sentence. Further, what error are you getting?

Comment: What's the structure/contents of `$variable_array`?

Comment: Is: explode(", ", $string); I fix my question code

Comment: `echo explode(", ", $string)` should give `Warning(Notice): Array to string conversion`

Comment: sorry, i try to simplify the question but I miss that, it is: echo $string.'<br/>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword with [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (`$$`):

Add the following line into the function body

```php
global $$str;
```

So the full code becomes:

```php
<?php

$name = '1 value';
$age  = '2 value';
$date = '3 value';
$string = "date, name, age";

function toImplode($string) { $line=''; foreach(explode(", ", $string) as $str){ global $$str; $line .= $$str.'|';} return $line;} 

echo 'Variable to line formatted order is: '.toImplode($string).'<br/>';
```

Output:

```
Variable to line formatted order is: 3 value|1 value|2 value|<br/>
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5BboMwELz7FSOEtImEqNre6pCe84HeF9gAkrEtY6pIad9ODVTNodIedmZnZsf3fllO7773SuWWR0EFesYnm1lIq5w7wUq9PKiW46Z6fVBTDIPtEpmtxwJrUIHkzbRS19k2cXAW0V1Gb1wrh1/DEXfkZrBSEWlcXRBu@oPcdlFWIM2flKdtP97RGVezQb5CvQegrHZc0hfpbwSJc7D7LUGlpOkd6IPDwLWRVAWbLf0cOUZp4UIrAcP0Bir/Fy3pVIenM@ll@QE)

Comment: Output should be: 3 value|1 value|2 value|
And not var names, as you said: date|name|age|

Comment: Please see my edit, I fully misunderstood the question ;)

Answer (score -1):

Having run this through a debugger, I believe I've located the issue - If the error you're referring to is the undefined variable errors for `date`, `name`, and `age`, this is due to [scoping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) - In a PHP function, the code within that function cannot see or access variables that are set outside of that function unless you define them as `global`, or pass them as parameters to the function.

You would do this by using the `global` keyword in the function - I.e., to make the variables `$name`, `$date`, and `$age` accessible, you'd add this line: `global $name, $date, $age;`. In the context of your script, `global $$str;` is technically valid and will run as well, although I'm not certain it'd be the best practice.

If you're referring to the `Array to string conversion` notice, this is caused by your `echo explode(...)` line - `explode()` returns an array, which cannot be cast back into a string. You might want to try [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead for outputting array contents.

Comment: sorry, I tried to simplify the question but I miss this: echo $string.'<br/>'; Now the question is fixed.